# Change class in layout file mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout page which consists of the standard Header and Footer and the `RenderBody()` function. My Header consists of a navigation with big buttons across the top as modules in the system

```
Customer    Quote    Jobs     etc
```

My question is I want to be able to give these buttons a class of active on load depending on which has been clicked. Do I need to do this in javascript or is there anyway I can pass model data or some variable to the layout file to set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following function to achieve this:

```
public static string MarkActive<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,string url)
{
    if (html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath
        .ToLower().StartsWith(url.ToLower().Trim()))
        return "active";
    else
        return null;
}
```

It is an extension method I keep in a `HtmlExtensions.cs` file. I use it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="@Html.MarkActive("/home")"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.MarkActive("/microsite"><a href="/microsite">View Microsite</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.MarkActive("/settings")"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account/logout">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is probably a better solution, but this works for me. In short, you should examine the `HttpContext` of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach to highlight the selected menu item:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        @{Dictionary<string, string> menuList = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                { "Customer", "Customer" },
                { "Quote", "Quote" },
                { "Jobs", "Jobs" },
                { "etc", "etc" },
            };
        }
        @foreach (var item in menuList )
        { 
            <li @(Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"].Contains(item.Key) ? " class=active" : string.Empty)>
                <a href="/Home/@item.Key">@item.Value</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Where item.Key for actions names, item.Value for corresponding name in menu.